# clear data in screen with reset button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clear all values in Textbox, Radiobutton, Dropdown and checkbox in my view by clicking reset button.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>medication</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" name="zoo">
    <h2>MEDICATION</h2>
    <div class="med">
      <pre>        
        <label>dropdown1<sup>*</sup></label>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.medication, Model.medication,"Select dropdown1", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })   <button style="height:30px;" onclick="opendropdown1()" ;>search</button>    
        Prescription Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><br />
        <label>text1</label><input type="text" size="25" style="height:30px;" id="dir" name="dir"/> 
        electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" />Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no"/>No<br />
      </pre>
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type='reset' value='Reset' name='reset' onclick="return resetForm(this.form);"> </div>
  <div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/reset.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('form[name="zoo"] input:reset').click(function () {
    $('form[name="zoo"]')
        .find(':radio, :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').end()
        .find('textarea, :text, select').val('')

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: my script is not working i think! no change in my view if i click reset button

Comment: what is the browsers console telling you?

Comment: im new to this concept.i do no what is browser console?

Comment: @ashwanth just reload the page when reset button is clicked

Comment: @ashwanth please give credits to the person who answers correct for your for your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you wanted to do, you don't even need any javascript code

```html
                <form id="form1" name="zoo">
                    <h2>MEDICATION</h2>
                    <div class="med">
                        <pre>        
            <label>dropdown1<sup>*</sup></label>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.medication, Model.medication,"Select dropdown1", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })   <button style="height:30px;" onclick="opendropdown1()" ;>search</button>    
                Prescription Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><br />
        <label>text1</label><input type="text" size="25" style="height:30px;" id="dir" name="dir"/> 
        electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" />Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no"/>No<br />
    </pre>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: No problem ty for voting my answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<input type='reset' id='reset' value='Reset' name='reset' onclick="resetForm(this.form);"> 
$('#reset').on('click', function () {
     $('.sizetestdate,#dir').val('');
     $('#yes,#no').removeAttr('checked');
       return false;
})
```

It will work for you.
Just check 
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/p3un0gbr/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/0a2bmg8g/1/

```js
$('input:reset').click(function () {
  $('input[type=date], [type=text]').val('');
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" name="zoo">
                <h2>MEDICATION</h2>
                <div class="med">
                    <pre>        
        <label>dropdown1<sup>*</sup></label>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.medication, Model.medication,"Select dropdown1", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })   <button style="height:30px;" onclick="opendropdown1()" ;>search</button>    
            Prescription Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><br />
    <label>text1</label><input type="text" size="25" style="height:30px;" id="dir" name="dir"/> 
    electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" />Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no"/>No<br />
</pre>
        </div>
    </form>
        <hr />
        <div class="wrapper">
<input type='reset' value='Reset' name='reset' />    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
<script>
$("input[type='reset']").click(function(){
    $("input").val("");
    $("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the reset button inside the `form`. No Javascript required. See the code below.

```
<form id="form1" name="zoo">
   <h2>MEDICATION</h2>
   <div class="med">
     <pre>        
        <label>dropdown1<sup>*</sup></label>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.medication, Model.medication,"Select dropdown1", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })   <button style="height:30px;" onclick="opendropdown1()" ;>search</button>    
            Prescription Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><br />
    <label>text1</label><input type="text" size="25" style="height:30px;" id="dir" name="dir"/> 
    electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" />Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no"/>No<br />
     </pre>
   </div>

   <hr />
   <div class="wrapper">
      <input type='reset' value='Reset' name='reset'>    
   </div>
 </form>
```